# How to configure products for multiple attributes

Tags: magento-1.8, attributes

I have a couple of products that have multiple attributes where the user can choose from, "Size" and "Color". But I can't seem to get them both working.

At first I created a product for every option like:

- Size 1 & Color 1;
- Size 1 & Color 2;
- Etc

But that only displayed the size, and yes I chose both attributes for the creation of the product. It did only display the name of the second attribute.

After that I created separate products like:

- Product A color 1;
- Product B size 1;

But that didn't seem to work either.

How would I get this to work?